# How to link all the nodes at the same level in a tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a binary tree:

```
struct node 
{
    int n; // value of node
    struct node *left; // left subtree
    struct node *right; // right subtree
    struct node *level; // level pointer (node “to the right”)
}
```

Initially, the level field is set to NULL.

I neet to write a function that will link all the nodes at the same level in a tree (not only from example, but any given tree).

```
void linkSameLevel(struct node *t);
```

And how can I know what the running time and memory usage of my function are for a tree of depth d containing n nodes?

Here what I have:

[image]

Here what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two queues for this purpose and BFS traversal.
And maintain two pointers currNode and prevNode.

1. Push root in Q1.
2. Start with Q1 and initialise `prevNode = null`.
3. Take from Q1 and then initialise `currNode` with it. Push the children of the currNode in Q2.
4. Now, if `prev != null`, then link `prevNode` with `currNode`.
5. Now `prevNode = currNode`.
6. Repeat from step 3 till Q1 is not empty.
7. When Q1 is empty. Set Q2 as Q1 and Q1 as Q2 (this new Q2 will be empty) and set `prevNode = null`. Go to Step 3.

   ```
   void linkSameLevel(node *root)
   {
       if (root = null)
           return;
       queue<node *> Q1, Q2;
       Q1.push(root);
       node *currNode; node *prevNode;
       prevNode = null;
       do
       {
           while (!Q1.empty())
           {
               node *currNode = Q1.pop();
               Q2.push(currNode.left); Q2.push(currNode.right);
               if (prevNode != null)
                   prevNode.level = currNode;
               prevNode = currNode;
           }
           swap(Q1, Q2);
       } while (!Q1.empty);
   }
   ```

Also take a look at [Level Order Traversal](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/)

Comment: What is `null`? Did you mean `NULL` or even better `nullptr`?

Comment: @MikeMB Thanks for editing the code properly. Can you let me know what was I missing or why was my code coming shabbily?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing which comes to my mind is that you need to use a queue to do a level order traversal.

And then link all the nodes of same level. Following link will provide a right direction :-

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/